# VPN connected, but no ping in both directions

Tags: vpn, openvpn, asus

Trying to set VPN between home and work routers. VPN connection is established and both sides can ping each other routers:

```
ping 192.168.1.1 from 192.168.0.0 network
```

and

```
ping 192.168.0.1 from 192.168.1.0 network
```

But it is not possible reach other PC's inside of network on both sides:

```
traceroute to 192.168.1.159 (192.168.1.159), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets
 1  10.8.0.6 (10.8.0.6)  4.772 ms  6.997 ms  20.582 ms
 2  *  *  *
 3  *  *  *
 4  *  *  *
```

and

```
traceroute to 192.168.0.96 (192.168.0.96), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets
 1  10.8.0.1 (10.8.0.1)  11.630 ms  1.777 ms  1.645 ms
 2  *  *  *
 3  *  *  *
 4  *  *  *
```

More configuration details:

Home:

```
OpenVPN client
192.168.1.0/24
```

Routing table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags    Metric Ref    Use Type Iface
default         78.61.551.254   0.0.0.0         UG       0      0        0 WAN0 vlan2
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.5        255.255.255.0   UG       0      0        0      tun14
10.8.0.5        *               255.255.255.255 UH       0      0        0      tun14
78.61.152.0     *               255.255.252.0   U        0      0        0 WAN0 vlan2
78.61.551.254   *               255.255.255.255 UH       0      0        0 WAN0 vlan2
192.168.0.0     10.8.0.5        255.255.255.0   UG       0      0        0      tun14
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U        0      0        0 LAN  br0
239.0.0.0       *               255.0.0.0       U        0      0        0 LAN  br0
```

Work:

```
OpenVPN server
192.168.0.0/24

Interface Type: TUN
Respond to DNS: Yes
Advertise DNS to clients: Yes
Push LAN to clients: Yes
Direct clients to redirect Internet traffic: No (as each site uses their own internet access for external traffic)
Manage Client-Specific Options: Yes
Allow Client <-> Client: Yes
Allow only specified clients: Yes

Allowed Clients:
Common name: client
Subnet : 192.168.1.0
Mask: 255.255.255.0
Push : Yes
```

Routing table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags    Metric Ref    Use Type Iface
10.8.0.2        *               255.255.255.255 UH       0      0        0      tun21
78.57.321.254   *               255.255.255.255 UH       0      0        0 WAN0 eth0
169.254.39.0    *               255.255.255.0   U        0      0        0 LAN  br0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG       0      0        0      tun21
192.168.1.0     10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG       0      0        0      tun21
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U        0      0        0 LAN  br0
78.57.120.0     *               255.255.252.0   U        0      0        0 WAN0 eth0
default         78.57.321.254   0.0.0.0         UG       0      0        0 WAN0 eth0
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Is ping the only protocol not working, but is other traffic woking as desired? Or is no traffic routed as expected?  - There  two different types of VPN architectures: the Site-to-Site VPN and Remote access VPN , or otherwise known as the Road Warrior VPN. You need the first to achieve proper bi-directional traffic between networks and that usually requires additional routing changes (in one or both networks). https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/site-to-site-routing-explained-in-detail/

Comment: And the linked Troubleshooting guide : https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/troubleshooting-reaching-systems-over-the-vpn-tunnel/